# python 2.7 Socket TCPserver with manager.dict /list cant pickle error

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

Dear more elevated pythoneers, i want to communicate between sockets over my socket server. For that i try to share a manager.dic with the threads and a manager.list to take commands from sockets. My code snipped runs on an can't pickle Error.

```
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer, object):
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, managerList, managerDict):
        super(ThreadedTCPServer, self).__init__(server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
        self.myTasks = managerList
        self.myThreads = managerDict

    def process_request_thread(self, request, client_address):
        try:
            self.finish_request(request, client_address)
            self.shutdown_request(request)
        except:
            self.handle_error(request, client_address)
            self.shutdown_request(request)
        finally:
            self.myThreads__delitem__(threading.current_thread().getName())
            print("Destroy Socket on Thread:", threading.current_thread().getName())

    def process_request(self, request, client_address):
        """Start a new thread to process the request."""
        t = threading.Thread(target = self.process_request_thread,
                             args = (request, client_address))
        t.daemon = False
        self.myThreads.__setitem__(t.getName(),t)
        t.start()       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    managerList = manager.list()
    managerDict = manager.dict()
    server = ThreadedTCPServer(("localhost", 12345), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler, managerList, managerDict)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
```

The moment the client connects, the error is thrown.

> Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 46048)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
>      self.process_request(request, client_address)
>    File "server.py", line 76, in process_request
>      self.myThreads.**setitem**(t.getName(),t)   File "", line 2, in **setitem**
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 758, in_callmethod
>      conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds)) TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects

I am coming from java and may understand the python things different than i should. Sorry for that.
Any suggestions? Thanks Holger